# Excel Aggregation function on arithmetic combinations without temporary column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I often want to do aggregate functions on linear combinations of columns without having to create a new column to hold the linear combination.  Is there a way to do this?

E.g., if my sheet has data in columns A:B, and I want the `STDEV` of the series A+B, right now I have to first create a new column C and fill with the formula `C2 = A2 + B2`.  Then I can get `=STDEV(C:C)`.

In this example: Is there a notation that allows me to skip the creation of Column C, and instead do something like STDEV(A:A+B:B)?

Comment: You can't reference the entire column, because blank cells seem to be treated as zero.  But you can use something like STDEV(A1:A50+B1:B50).  It is an array formula and must be entered with CTRL-Shift-Enter.

Comment: This works for the entire column references by replacing zeros with blanks:  `=STDEV(IF(A:A+B:B<>0,A:A+B:B,""))`.

Comment: @Bandersnatch – those are both good answers you should post so I can accept!  I hate array formulas and thought there was a way to do it without them, but now I'm remembering that the reason I hate array formulas is it's the only way to do this ;)

Comment: Done, and thanks.  To handle the text problem, this works whereas ANDing did not.:  `=AVERAGE(IF((A:A+B:B<>0)*NOT(ISTEXT(A:A+B:B)),A:A+B:B,""))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with adding the entire columns, because after the addition, blank cells are treated like zeros.  That doesn't happen with a single column reference of course, and I'd call this a bug.

You can get around this by using an IF() to replace the zeros with blanks:

`=AVERAGE(IF(A:A+B:B<>0,A:A+B:B,""))`

`=STDEV(IF(A:A+B:B<>0,A:A+B:B,""))`

[image]

The formulas with sums as the argument are array formulas and must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> , rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also note that any text in the columns being added (like headings) will cause a `#VALUE!` error.  **Edit:**  But this modification will handle that:

`=AVERAGE(IF((A:A+B:B<>0)*NOT(ISTEXT(A:A+B:B)),A:A+B:B,""))`

I hope this helps. Good luck.